# about a changeTab function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a French beginner of html code and I have a question. I want to make tabs on my website but the js code + html code don't work. So can you help me ? I will write the script :

```js
function changeTab(evt, target) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementById("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementById("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="changeTab(event, 'series')">Séries</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'animes')">Animés</button>
<div style="display: none" class="animes tabcontent">
```

I don't write the entire code but if you need more informations, I will post them.
Thanks !

I want to create 3 tabs on my website, but I don't understand how to do that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="series.css"rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="commande.css"rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title class="titreprincipal">Les meilleures séries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content"> 
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="#">Accueil</a>
                <a href="commande.html">Commandes</a>
                <a href="notes.html">Notes des séries</a>
                <a class="right" href="infos.html">Informations</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
<h1 class="h1_color">
    Les meilleures séries
</h1>
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="changeTab(event, 'series')">Séries</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'animes')">Animés</button>
</div>
<div class="'series' 'tabcontent'">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="breakingbad.jpg" alt="Image de Whalter White" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Breaking bad</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="breakingbad.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="bettercallsaul.jpg" alt="Image de Saul Goodman" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Better Call Sall</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="bettercallsaul.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="elcamino.jpg" alt="Image de Jesse Pinkman" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>El Camino</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="elcamino.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none" class="animes tabcontent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="bleach.jpg" alt="Image de Ichigo" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Bleach</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="bleach.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="naruto.jpg" alt="Image de Naruto" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Naruto</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="naruto.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="onepiece.jpg" alt="Image des Mugiwara" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>One piece</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="onepiece.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accueil.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: At a glance there appear to be a variety of problems here.  For example... `document.getElementById("tabcontent")` - There is no element with that `id`.  `i < tabcontent` - You're comparing a number with an HTML element, which makes no sense.  `tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";` - An HTML element (even if one was found) isn't an array.  Etc.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems.

1. document.getElementById only returns 1 element. You should use document.getElementsByClassName in your case and use class instead of id.

```js
tabcontents = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
```

```js
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
```

2. In your for loop, the second condition is wrong. It should be the length of the elements not the elements themselves.
3. You should call .replace on .className

```js
for (i = 0; i < tabcontents.length; i++) {
  tabcontents[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```js
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
```

**Update:**

```js
function changeTab(evt, target) {
    var i, tabcontents, tablinks;
    tabcontents = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontents.length; i++) {
        tabcontents[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    const targetElement = document.getElementById(target);
    if(targetElement) {
        targetElement.style.display = "block";
    }
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="series.css"rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="commande.css"rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title class="titreprincipal">Les meilleures séries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content"> 
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li>
                <a class="active" href="#">Accueil</a>
                <a href="commande.html">Commandes</a>
                <a href="notes.html">Notes des séries</a>
                <a class="right" href="infos.html">Informations</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
<h1 class="h1_color">
    Les meilleures séries
</h1>
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks active" onclick="changeTab(event, 'series')">Séries</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="changeTab(event, 'animes')">Animés</button>
</div>
<div class="tabcontent" id="series">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="breakingbad.jpg" alt="Image de Whalter White" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Breaking bad</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="breakingbad.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="bettercallsaul.jpg" alt="Image de Saul Goodman" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Better Call Sall</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="bettercallsaul.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="elcamino.jpg" alt="Image de Jesse Pinkman" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>El Camino</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="elcamino.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none" class="tabcontent" id="animes">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="bleach.jpg" alt="Image de Ichigo" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Bleach</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="bleach.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="naruto.jpg" alt="Image de Naruto" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>Naruto</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="naruto.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-33">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="onepiece.jpg" alt="Image des Mugiwara" class="avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4>One piece</h4>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <button class="button primary2" formaction="onepiece.html" formtarget="_self">
                        Accéder
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accueil.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I do theses changes but the code still not working...

Comment: I found these problems in your code that you've uploaded. It wasn't the whole solution. You should post the other part of your codes too.

Comment: thank you I uploaded the entire code html. Can you watch ? Thanks a lot

Comment: MERCI BEAUCOUP ! I understand my mistakes. Have a nice day

Comment: You're welcome! Please pick my answer as the correct answer if it helped you.